# Cannot resolve symbol length

Tags: java, android, arrays, image, bitmapfactory

I want to retrieve a list of images from SQLite.

This is my 'getImage()' method

```
    public List<byte[]> getImage(int i) {
    List<byte[]> list = new ArrayList<>();
    String selectImage = "SELECT VocabImage FROM Vocab WHERE VocabTopic =" + i;
    Cursor c = database.rawQuery(selectImage, null);
    if(c.moveToFirst())
        do{
            list.add(c.getBlob(c.getColumnIndex("VocabImage")));
        }while(c.moveToNext());

    c.close();
    return list;
}
```

This is my java class where I want to call my getImage() method. But there is an error saying that it cannot resolve symbol 'length' in (data.length) in the BitmapFactory line. Anyone has any idea how to solve this? Thank you.

```
 Intent intent = getIntent();

 int topicId = intent.getIntExtra("SelectedTopicId", 1);

 databaseAccess.open();

 List<byte[]>data = databaseAccess.getImage(topicId);

 Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);

 imageView.setImageBitmap(image);
```

Comment: Your `data` is a `List`, you either need to do `data.get(x)` of sort to get the array before you use it.

Comment: If you store images in a database. Its not an adviced strategy to do that since it leads to long call which lead your app to ANRs. Modify your storage ways!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
```

change to

```
Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data.get(position), 0, data.get(position).length);  // pass position for which you want length.
```

Comment: i changed and it says my first argument (data) is wrong.

Comment: see my edits.. change your data to data.get(position)

Answer (score 0):

you need to change like this: list.get(0).length for get image at index 0.